# Reverse incomplete car importation before car is registered and ownership is transferred

Tags: usa, canada, car, imports

My brother (Canadian) wanted to give me his car so he drove to the US (I'm American) and went to the CBP to import the car to the US. The title was, and still is, in his name (I was not involved in the importation process). Due to unforeseen events he will be keeping his car and should take it back to Canada. As said, we have not went to the DMV and have not transferred ownership. The title is still Canadian and is still in his name, it just has the CBP stamp on it.

I was wondering what would it take to reverse such procedure? I tried calling the CBP for days. Today they answered but due to Veterans day they could not give me clear-cut answer. I was told the car needed to be exported from the US to Canada through Automated Export System and ITN form. Unfortunately the agent was unable to guide me on getting the ITN form or how to go through with it.

Is anyone familiar with this situation and how to get it done? What is the ITN form and where do we get one?

Comment: As the vehicle is still titled in and licensed by Canada, I'd just try driving it north (with a letter in your possession explaining the circumstances and signed by your brother) back into Canada.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica thanks, we did almost just that. We needed to call CBP and confirm with them to cancel the importation forms first. I made an answer of the whole thing in case anyone has such an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bunch of phone calls, a visit to the DMV, and another bunch of phone calls here is what I got:

1) US-CBP (none importation/exportation expert): you need ITN and AES and you gotta export the car to Canada.

2) DMV: This title is Canadian, registered to a Canadian and has nothing to do with us. As far as we're concerned, this car is still Canadian. It may only not be as such according to the CBP so get back to them.

3) CBSA (Canadian CBP): the car is still Canadian if it was never registered in the US. You could just drive back, but you need to call and confirm with US CBP first.

4) US-CBP: what's your name and when was the car imported? (information given)... A bit later ... Okay so we cancelled the paperwork and if there is any issue we will call you back. Just drive the car back and you should have no issues.

So it happened. All was needed was asking the CBP to cancel the forms internally (nothing to do on our side except that) and you can drive the car back.

I hope this helps anyone in similar situation.

Please note that if the car was registered in the US and went through the DMV, then it MUST be exported as if it is an American car.